# How to get the content of a file from the net?

Tags: php, http

I have coded like this

```
$xml=http_get('https://vnexpress.net/rss/khoa-học.rss');
```

but it has error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function http_get() in C:\Apache24\htdocs\abc.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\abc.php on line 22
```

I also coded

```
$doc=DOMDocument::load('https://vnexpress.net/rss/khoa-hoc.rss');
```

errors

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\Apache24\htdocs\abc.php on line 17

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "https://vnexpress.net/rss/khoa-hoc.rss" in C:\Apache24\htdocs\abc.php on line 17
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why not try using [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of inventing a mythical function and hoping that it might work

Comment: Instead of guessing at function names, try using a search engine like duckduckgo or google.

Comment: try file_get_contents() you are making your own library.

Comment: Try this code. $rss_data = file_get_contents('https://vnexpress.net/rss/khoa-hoc.rss'); $rss_data will have the complete response.

Comment: It is done by using file_get_contents. But I also want to try another way, by using http_get and DOMDocument::load, please tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: If you want to use `http_get()`, the you need to have the PECL http extension installed

Answer (score 0):

You can use the " file_get_contents" method like this :

```
$test = file_get_contents('https://vnexpress.net/rss/khoa-hoc.rss');
echo $test;
```

Comment: It appeared the warnings

    Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to find the wrapper "https" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in C:\Apache24\htdocs\abc.php on line 23

    Warning: file_get_contents(https://vnexpress.net/rss/khoa-hoc.rss): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Apache24\htdocs\abc.php on line 23

Comment: The problem is solved when I uncommented out the line ";extension=openssl" in php.ini